# File.Copy() performance if a file already exists

Tags: c#, performance, file, file-io, copy

I have a project that runs as a scheduled task every 5 minutes. Among other things, the project runs through hundreds of images and copies them to a network drive in this manner:

```
foreach (string file in Files)
{
    string Control = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        try
        {
            File.Copy(file, destinationFolder + "\\" + Control + @".pdf", false);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            Console.Writeline(err.ToString());
        }
}
```

The "false" argument, of course, is telling it NOT to overwrite a file if it already exists.

Is this faster/better practice than first checking if the file already exists and then only copying if the file does not exist? (see below)

```
foreach (string file in Files)
{
    if (File.Exists(destinationFolder + "\\" + ControlNumber + ".pdf") == false)
    {
        File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
        File.Copy(file, destinationFolder + "\\" + ControlNumber + @".pdf");
    }
}
```

My gut tells me that the first is the better way. However, I'm relatively new to programming and would love to know which is better, faster, more widely accepted, etc..

It may or may not be helpful to know that the remote drive/folder I am copying to contains 4TB of image data (millions of images).

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you write all of the existing files' path into a text or xml file, and then check against that list first, if it is not in that list, then copy into directory and then add new file to the list? Just an idea :)

Comment: how did you create the `Files` collection?

Comment: It looks like in one case you're doing a `Copy` and in the other case you're doing a `Move`. Unlikely to be performance-relevant, but likely to be correctness-relevant.

Comment: Aside from the Copy/Move difference, the examples are not quite the same thing.  In the second example, the could possibly show up between the File.Exists and the File.Move/Copy calls, which would lead to an odd exception.

Comment: @ Felipe Oriani: string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder + "\\", "*.pdf");

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: Are you re-implementing a robocopy call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tested this on a local drive with the following results:

1000 times checking if file exists, then doing a `File.Copy` if it does not: **28.29 milliseconds**

1000 times doing a `File.Copy` with overwrite set to false in a `try, catch`: **317.13 milliseconds**

Tested on a network drive with the following results:

1000 times checking if file exists, then doing a `File.Copy` if it does not: **203.48 milliseconds**

1000 times doing a `File.Copy` with overwrite set to false in a `try, catch`: **14758.74 milliseconds**

Based on that, I would think it's clear that doing a file check first would be more efficient.

Comment: Very interesting, bordering on counter-intuitive. After employing the stopwatch to my 2 options, I am seeing very similar results.

Comment: In my test, it should be noted that it was trying the same file, so it existed every time.

Comment: what i think needs to be added here is that try/catch blocks take a lot of CPU to process... it maybe what's slowing down, but it doesn't matter. the 2nd way is much better.

Comment: I'd love to see this test done when the target file *doesn't* exist. So 8 results instead of 4.

Answer (score 2):

You are much more likely to see better performance using the first case (though make sure you wrap the call to `File.Copy` in a `try..catch`, since it will throw an `IOException` if the file does exist. Your first example lets the underlying platform handle the checks for file existence, which it may optimize in ways that your code cannot. Due to the round-trip time across the network for each call you make, drastically reducing the number of calls will have a performance gain.

In addition, the remote system might change between your call to `File.Exists` and `File.Copy`, and the latter will potentially overwrite files that are created between when you check and when you start the copy.

A much better approach would be to create a list of files on the remote machine first and then only copy the files that don't already exist. When you do this copy, use your first method with the `try..catch`. This ensures that you don't waste time trying to copy files that were there when you started and also ensure that you don't accidentally overwrite a file that is created after you start copying things across.

Comment: I see that you say there are millions of files, but they are probably not all in one directory. If the number of directories you are moving files to is large compared to the number of files (probably something like 1:5, but you would have to profile to find the right number) then you just want to use the first technique. If the number of directories is small and the number of files you are copying is large, that single transfer of the names of all files in each of the directories you care about is small compared to the number of round trips you have to make if you try to copy each file.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those is likely to be the fastest way to approach the problem. What I'd do is do a `Directory.GetFiles` call on your remote drive, compare the results, and only copy the files you need.

That way there's only one network ls-equivalent operation and only as many copy operations as you need.

Comment: The remote drive is 4TB large with millions of image files. Sounds a little inefficient.

Comment: @ColtonMilne You should look at `rsync` and its algorithms.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Thanks +1, rsync is very interesting, albeit slightly more complex than what I wanted for a simple app.